# Oauth with Plumber API in R

Tags: r, api, plumber

I have created a sample function using `plumber` package.

```
#* @get /tags

printmyname <- function(x) print(x)
```

When I run the following procedure.

```
library(plumber)
r <- plumb("plumber_Usman2.R")  
r$run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8000)
```

An API is exposed on my local host which I can access using the host of my `R server`.

Something like

> http://host:8000/tags?x="This design looks bad, please fix it"

My Question is, since the API is open and can be openly access by anyone with the link, I want to secure it using Oauth. I have been doing research but couldn't come across anything. I would be thankful if someone can guide me in this regards with either `plumber` or any other package which can secure my `API.`  Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Please see https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html. The only option that supports OAuth out-of-the-box is [RStudio Connect](https://www.rstudio.com/products/connect/). You could also consider trying to use the Docker approach and fronting the service with nginx or Apache which may be able to handle the authentication, but it's a bit involved.

Comment: Are you aware of any other package that allows building API with oAuth? or any other protection layer.